# How to redirect the search engine using Safari App Extension

Tags: ios, swift, safari, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

I am trying to implement a safari app extension where every search in the safari address bad gets redirected to another search engine(in this care, to DuckDuckGo, just as an example). I have managed to do this much. However, using this logic, if the user opens [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and searches in their search bar, the logic tries to redirect those searches as well. How do I stop that from happening?

```
//My SafariExtensionHandler file has the following functions:
//Given a Google, Yahoo, or Bing URL, this function will return the url encoding
func getQueryStringParameter(url: String) -> String? {
var param = "q"
if url.contains("search.yahoo.com") {
        param = "p"
    }
guard let url = URLComponents(string: url) else { return nil }
let rawString = url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
let percentEncoding = rawString?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)?.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "%26")
return percentEncoding
}


// Before every page navigaion, this code checks if it's navigating to a search engine site. If so, it parses the url in order to instead navigate to that same seach term on DuckDuckGo.

override func page(_ page: SFSafariPage, willNavigateTo url: URL?) {
let hostnames = ["www.google.com", "www.bing.com", "search.yahoo.com"]
let url = url!
if hostnames.contains(url.host!) {
if let query = self.getQueryStringParameter(url: url.absoluteString) {
let redirectedURL = URL(string: "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=\(query)&ia=web")!
            page.getContainingTab { (tab) in
                tab.navigate(to: redirectedURL)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that this finctionality is provided in the iOS Settings for Safari under 'Search Engine? And 'DuckDuckGo' is listed too!

Comment: Yes. But DuckDuckGo is just an example. I am asking on a general term. Like what if I wanted to change it to Ecosia, for example. In fact, Ecosia have an extension where they have implemented it.